# Get manufacturer logo by manufacturer id or name in Prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I want to get the logo image of manufacturer on product list page.
At this time i upload the logo manual and i entere a hard coded path:

```
{$content_dir}themes/jms_enter/img/brand/{$product.manufacturer_name|replace:' ':'_'}.png
```

I want to get the manufacturer logo uploaded in the backend.

Tried this :  `{$img_manu_dir}{$product->id_manufacture}-medium.jpg` but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks

```
<img src="{$img_manu_dir}{$product.id_manufacturer}.jpg" alt="{$product.manufacturer_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.manufacturer_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
```